# Json schema validation: Unique key in json array

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have following JSON data:

```
[
  {
  "unique1":{
    "value":3
    }
  },
  {
  "unique2":{
    "value":4
    }
  }
]
```

Each array item has a json object with one top level unique key.
When i try to write a validation schema for it I can only validate that the full array is unique but not the top level key in each array.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "uniqueItems": true,
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "patternProperties": {
      "^.*$": {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Following JSON data should fail to validate:

```
[
  {
  "unique1":{
    "value":3
    }
  },
  {
  "unique1":{
    "value":4
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: If name uniqueness isn't important, I'd suggest using the IDs as the object keys instead, and convert the list of objects into an object of objects. An example can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987954/2868017

Comment: The key needs to be unique. Renamed id to value to emphasize that it does not act as an id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard JSON Schema keyword that allows to express this validation requirement.

[Ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) (for JavaScript) has a custom keyword "uniqueItemProperties" (in [ajv-keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords/blob/master/README.md#uniqueitemproperties) package) that does what you ask for.

You may propose it for the next versions of the standard.